AES-256-CBC Encrpyt in Java / Decrypt in Node - error:1C80006B:Provider routines::wrong final block length
I am trying to use AES-256-CBC encryption to encrypt some strings in Java and then decrypt them in a Node.js application using the crypto library.
Here is the Java encryption:
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class TestEncrypt {
    public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt, String key, byte[] initialVector,String salt) throws Exception{
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(initialVector);
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(key.toCharArray(), salt.getBytes(), 65536, 256);
        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
    
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivspec);
        return URLEncoder.encode(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
    }
    
    public static byte[] decodeToBase64(String base64Value) {
        return Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Value);
    }
    
    public static String encryptData(String StringToEncode, String base256Key, String base256Iv, String salt) throws Exception {
        String encryptedString = encrypt(StringToEncode, base256Key, decodeToBase64(base256Iv), salt);
        return encryptedString;
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String originalValue = "hello world";
        String encryptedValue = encryptData(originalValue, "TSP88GUiIrX5ZyBWAkvWk7JUMBaSlkVADhEB6gsGS9s=", "ZUCKXBlZT6/SdBxLoEJl0Q==", "ssshhhhhhhhhhh!!!!");
        System.out.println("originalValue=" + originalValue);
        System.out.println("encryptedValue=" + encryptedValue);
    }
}

Here is the Node.js decryption:
const algorithm = 'aes-256-cbc';
const digest = 'sha256';

function decrypt(strToDecrypt, secretKey, salt, initialVector) {
    const key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(
        secretKey,
        Buffer.from(salt),
        65536,
        32,
        digest
        );
    const iv = Buffer.from(initialVector, 'base64');

    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
    let decrypted = decipher.update(strToDecrypt, 'base64');
    decrypted += decipher.final();
    return decrypted;
}

decrypt('V7qjZNuL%2FKBWRWc3hx1wRw%3D%3D', 'TSP88GUiIrX5ZyBWAkvWk7JUMBaSlkVADhEB6gsGS9s=', 'ssshhhhhhhhhhh!!!!', 'ZUCKXBlZT6/SdBxLoEJl0Q==');

The issue is that when I try to decrypt what I encrypted in the Java application, I am getting this error
error:1C80006B:Provider routines::wrong final block length


The bug is in the decrypt() call, which was included in the originally posted code and was later removed (why?), s. https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/78674572/1. In this decrypt() call you pass the plaintext instead of the ciphertext, which of course does not work, because you want to decrypt the ciphertext and not the plaintext. Fix: Just pass the ciphertext. Then decryption works.

@Topaco, thanks for that prompt response, and sorry I was missing a couple lines of code that did an additional URLEncoder.encode into UTF-8 on the Java side, just edited the code block again

If you additionally URL encode the ciphertext in the Java code after the Base64 encoding, you must URL decode it in the NodeJS code before the Base64 decoding. JavaScript provides decodeURIComponent() for URL decoding. Replace 'V7qjZNuL%2FKBWRWc3hx1wRw%3D%3D' with decodeURIComponent('V7qjZNuL%2FKBWRWc3hx1wRw%3D%3D') in the decrypt() call.

Note that there is also a URL safe Base64 variant (RFC 4648 §5: base64url).

@Topaco thanks that fixed the errors, but I am trying on a payload (should be a large json) provided by the encrypting team and I am getting something like this after decryption:
���Q%�a�9�D��w���k~�,���o�!YMb�pl�>vO$��9جS�"���D)H�
��V>�Vr »����8*�(��c��-�����]��WJ!
����xF�ބ��i4�@�R"��j��F���a���|�C�旾%��?�si{L��0�C�{j��o�Ͱcë}��T�m~<6V�Я�K#��[��"8�@O6����b��~J�A>�������� ����㲯
�������^�����$>jxZ�/�$

Was the ciphertext generated with this Java code? If not, the encryption logic of the code used and the NodeJS decryption logic may be different. If yes, the key and ciphertext probably do not match, possibly due to a different password or different PBKDF2 parameters. You will need to consult with the other party to find out which of these applies.
